# Tricky nested match.url in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want a component which renders on every route, and has child components (e.g. a header).

By leaving out `exact` in the route I can achieve that.

```
render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Inside the component, I have nested routes:

```
const App = ({match}) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.url}login`} component={LoginForm}/>
      <Route path={`${match.url}panel`} component={ControlPanel}/>
    </Switch>
);
```

It picks one out of two components to render, based on the path.

As shown in the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) we need to use the match url. This was very confusing to me, since the `match.url` is `/`, and blindly following the examples I wrote e.g. `'{`${match.url}/login`}'`, which results in `//login`
`

My question: if I do not match a parameter, why can't I use a full path in the child?

The following does not work when used inside `App`:

```
<Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
```

Comment: I use ver3 but the way I setup my router should apply to your case. If you want to render a component on every route you don't need to provide a path. Do something like this: <Route component={NavPanel}>

Comment: Inside of NavPanel you refer to nested components as props.children. This way all your router logic can be placed in one place. I can give a more complete answer if you so require.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem, but does not answer my question  :)

Comment: I dont quite understand what the question is. Are you saying that using  **path={`${match.url}login`}** is equivalent to **path="/login"** but the latter does not work?

Comment: Almost. Is does work, but not when nested.

Comment: If it works when not nested its because its taking from the root path "/". If you have a nested route the path has to be relative to the parent

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly. I think you should use `path` instead of `url`.

```
const App = ({match}) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/login`} component={LoginForm}/>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/panel`} component={ControlPanel}/>
    </Switch>
);
```